# From Linux jenknins call batch command on remote windows server

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on Linux environment and would like to call a batch file on windows server. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved w/ https://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/

Also, there are other options, like using SSH to connect to the windows machine and launch the script.